# understanding prefixes for bone name

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

STL, STR, ORG, Tan etc. - What do all these prefixes mean? Is there a complete list of them with a decoding and description of their meaning?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If have further details please add them to your previous post by editing it, rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: There is no set of rules prefixes follow. It's up to the rigger. You will need to ask the guy who created the names.